# Retrieving CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

How can I retrieve CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto using PHP? It appears as a header in the AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomRemovedHeaders

I tried using `$_SERVER['CLOUDFRONT_FORWARDED_PROTO']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_FORWARDED_PROTO']`, among others, but without success.

How can I do it? What am I missing? I can't find any information or examples on this at all.

Answer (score 3):

Have you configured ClouldFront to forward the header? It doesn't forward it by default.

`CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-protocol